# How I fix this $_GET array issue?

Tags: php, get

There is a problem in my search page. when page is loading there is a value comes from URL something like this.

```
http://localhost/myweb/search.php?subject=Business+%26+Accounting+Studies
```

This value used to show my search result. First of all I check this value to make sure it is true or not, its is string or not etc, on my page.

Validation code:

```
// Check for a valid keyword from search input:
if ((isset($_GET['subject'])) && (is_string ($_GET['subject']))) {

    foreach ( $_GET AS $key => $subject) {
        $searchKey = $key;
        $searchKeyword = '%'.$subject.'%';
    }

    echo '<pre>', print_r( $_GET), '</pre>';

}else { // No valid keyword, kill the script.
    echo 'This page has been accessed in error.';
    include ('includes/footer.html');
    exit();
}
```

This code working for me at the moment. But my problem encounter me when I passing another variable through the URL after search page loaded. Why I pass this 2 variable is I need to filter my search result under some conditions.

I use 2 HTML links on my search.php page to pass this 2 variables. Its something like this.

```
echo '<li><a href="?tutor=link">Tutor</a></li>
      <li><a href="?institute=link">Institute</a></li>';
```

And I check this value like this :

```
$tutor = isset($_GET['institute']) ? '0' : '1'; 
$institute = isset($_GET['tutor']) ? '0' : '1';
```

My problem is when page load first time its displaying all search result correctly. But clicking on filtering links it is not working and not display any search result at all on the page.

**UPDATE:** debugging result.

This is `print_r($_GET)` result when page loading first time.

```
Array
(
    [subject] => Mathematics
)
```

It become something like this when I clicking on a link that I use to filter (tutor, institute)

```
Array
(
    [subject] => Mathematics
    [tutor] => link
)
```

filtering not happening and not display any result on the page.

It becomes like this when I clicking on the same link again.

```
Array
(
    [subject] => link
    [tutor] => link
)
```

Again filtering not happening and not display any result on the page.

Can anybody tell me how I fix this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Well... `?tutor=link` doesn't set `subject`.

Comment: I tried changing it like this but not working - <li><a href="?subject='.$subject.'&tutor=link">Tutor</a></li> check my updated question.

Comment: better paste your assigning code, where you assigning values to $subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your links are not correct.

you need to add 2nd variable to url.
$subject = $_GET['subject'];

```
echo '<li><a href="?tutor=link&subject='.$subject.'">Tutor</a></li>
      <li><a href="?institute=link&subject='.$subject.'">Institute</a></li>';
```

Also don't you think this

```
$tutor = isset($_GET['institute']) ? '0' : '1'; 
$institute = isset($_GET['tutor']) ? '0' : '1';
```

should be

```
$tutor = isset($_GET['institute']) ? '1' : '0'; //if set then 1
$institute = isset($_GET['tutor']) ? '1' : '0'; //if set then 1
```

---

and

```
foreach ( $_GET AS $key => $subject) {
        $searchKey = $key;
        $searchKeyword = '%'.$subject.'%';
    }
```

to

```
foreach ( $_GET AS $key => $subject) {

if ($key == 'subject') {
            $searchKey = $key;
            $searchKeyword = '%'.$subject.'%';
     }
}
```

Comment: can you tell me where I place this two lines.. $tutor = isset($_GET['institute']) ? '1' : '0'; //if set then 1
$institute = isset($_GET['tutor']) ? '1' : '0'; //if set then 1

Comment: replace these two lines  `$tutor = isset($_GET['institute']) ? '0' : '1'; 
$institute = isset($_GET['tutor']) ? '0' : '1';`

Comment: sometimes print_r($_GET) output like this... Array
(
    [tutor] => link
    [subject] => Business 
    [Accounting_Studies] => 
)

Comment: Business & Accounting Studies is a subject

Comment: Ok.. I changed my links like this - echo '<li><a href="?tutor=link&subject='.urlencode($subject).'">Tutor</a></li>
      <li><a href="?institute=link&subject='.urlencode($subject).'">Institute</a></li>';

Comment: yes it is working now.. thank you for your help and thanks for every answers.

Answer (score 1):

When you click one of your links, it will essentially send you to `http://localhost/myweb/search.php?tutor=link` or `http://localhost/myweb/search.php?institute=link` respectively. What you need to do is something more like

```
echo '<li><a href="?subject=' . $_GET['subject'] . '&tutor=link">Tutor</a></li>
      <li><a href="?subject=' . $_GET['subject'] . '&institute=link">Institute</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try to use `urlencode();` and `urldecode();`
```

think it will solve your problem. check http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php
for further help

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you replace your search keyword in foreach loop:

```
foreach ( $_GET AS $key => $subject) {
    $searchKey = $key;
    $searchKeyword = '%'.$subject.'%';
}
```

so if you have $_GET with subject and tutor the result would be:

```
$searchkey = 'tutor';
$searchkeyword = '%link%';
```

which is not correct.
Simply write:

```
$searchkey = 'subject';
$searchkeyword = "%{$_GET['subject']}%";
```

and do not use foreach.

**EDIT**
the whole thing would be:

```
// Check for a valid keyword from search input:
if ((isset($_GET['subject'])) && (is_string ($_GET['subject']))) {

    // foreach ( $_GET AS $key => $subject) {
        $searchKey = 'subject';
        $searchKeyword = '%' . $_GET['subject'] . '%';
    // }

    echo '<pre>', print_r( $_GET), '</pre>';

} else { // No valid keyword, kill the script.
    echo 'This page has been accessed in error.';
    include ('includes/footer.html');
    exit();
}
```